# Magicsuggest replace letters when user is typing

Tags: jquery

i use the Magicsuggest with JSON Output.

In my database i have some Words with html for example ä = & auml; and so on.

The Magicsuggest-List shows the html tags correctly. But it is not possible to search for it.

For example: When the user types München, the suggest is 0, when the User types München the suggest is 1.

Can i replace the ü to & uuml; in the background?

Answer (score 0):

The list of combo options that fills the component is provided by your server call. Transform the data's html entities on the server side before serving them to MagicSuggest.